# C++ How can I read phrases from a text file?

Tags: c++

I am currently using this to read 1 word at a time from a text file:

```
int Dictionary::processFile(string file) {    //receives a text file name to be read from user
    string word;
    int wordCount = 0;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(file.c_str());
    if (fin.fail( )) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Input file opening failed.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    while (fin >> word) {
        word = trimString(word);    //trimString removes any symbols including spaces and words. only reads words.
        exTree.ExtAvlTree_processNode(word);    //processNode simply inserts the word into an avl tree. irrelevant to the question
        wordCount++;
    }
    fin.close();
    return wordCount;
}
```

How can i modify it to be able to read 2-3 words at a time before it process the word. for example it reads a word then process it then it reads the same word but add the next adjacent word so it becomes a phrase (consisting of 2 words) then it reads the same 2 words but add the 3rd next word to be another phrase.

extra question, if the above is acheiveable:

How can i stop trimString function from removing spaces and only remove symbols?

This is the trim string function:

```
 string Dictionary::trimString(string input){
    stringstream ss;
    for (int x = 0; x < (int) input.size(); x++) {
        if(isalpha(input[x])){
            ss << input[x];
        }
    }

    if (ss.str().length() > 0) {
        return ss.str();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: "How can i stop trimString function from removing spaces and only remove symbols?" -> aren't spaces symbols anymore?

Comment: @ForceBru How can i exempt space from it?

Comment: *"How can i stop trimString function from removing spaces and only remove symbols"*...`fin >> word` will not read spaces since it uses them as a deliminator to stop the extraction. so why do you want to check for spaces in the word when it doesn't have any?

Comment: @bkVnet thats why i mentioned "if the above is achieveable" since i need to read the spaces if im going to be reading phrases.

Comment: you could probably do `if(isalpha(input[x]) || input[x]==' ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add each word you read to a std::vector, then you could use a for loop to use them in the manner you described. The code below is an example of something you could do

```
  vector<string> words;
  string word = "";
  ifstream infile("words.txt", ios::in);

  while (infile >> word)
  {
    /*
     you can process each word here like removing commas, periods 
     and such(if that is in fact what you want) before you add 
     them to the vector
    */
    words.push_back(word);
  }

  string phrase = "";

  for (int k = 0; k < words.size(); k++)
  {
    phrase +=  " " + words[k];
    cout << phrase << endl;
  }
```

In the example, I assume you want the words in the phrases to be space separated